# Need an array of Permutation list of numbers in php

Tags: php, arrays, permutation

Here I need an array of all the numbers generated by permutation and also here i am giving n and k from a html form.

```
function combination_number($k,$n){

    $n = intval($n);
    $k = intval($k);
    if ($k > $n){
        return 0;
    } elseif ($n == $k) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if ($k >= $n - $k){
            $l = $k+1;
            for ($i = $l+1 ; $i <= $n ; $i++)
                $l *= $i;
            $m = 1;
            for ($i = 2 ; $i <= $n-$k ; $i++)
                $m *= $i;
        } else {
            $l = ($n-$k) + 1;
            for ($i = $l+1 ; $i <= $n ; $i++)
                $l *= $i;
            $m = 1;
            for ($i = 2 ; $i <= $k ; $i++)
                $m *= $i;            
        }
    }
    return $l/$m;
}

function array_combination($le, $set){

    $lk = combination_number($le, count($set));
    $ret = array_fill(0, $lk, array_fill(0, $le, '') );

    $temp = array();
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $le ; $i++)
        $temp[$i] = $i;

    $ret[0] = $temp;

    for ($i = 1 ; $i < $lk ; $i++){
        if ($temp[$le-1] != count($set)-1){
            $temp[$le-1]++;
        } else {
            $od = -1;
            for ($j = $le-2 ; $j >= 0 ; $j--)
                if ($temp[$j]+1 != $temp[$j+1]){
                    $od = $j;
                    break;
                }
            if ($od == -1)
                break;
            $temp[$od]++;
            for ($j = $od+1 ; $j < $le ; $j++)    
                $temp[$j] = $temp[$od]+$j-$od;
        }
        $ret[$i] = $temp;
    }
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $lk ; $i++)
        for ($j = 0 ; $j < $le ; $j++)
            $ret[$i][$j] = $set[$ret[$i][$j]];   

    return $ret;
}
$number = $_REQUEST['number'];

for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++)
{
   $arr[$i]=$i+1;
}
$k = $_REQUEST['select'];
$permutations = array_combination($k, $arr);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($permutations);
```

This code is working but its not giving all the numbers generated by Permutation. I need those numbers also. Please tell me how can i get those? Please help.

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output based on a given input?

Comment: Suppose n=3 and k=2 then output is :

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

)

But here I want also with the above


 [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )
   [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
        )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the best solution, but this seems to do what you want

```
function array_combination($le, $set){
    // Your existing code
    // …

    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $lk ; $i++)
        for ($j = 0 ; $j < $le ; $j++)
            $ret[$i][$j] = $set[$ret[$i][$j]];

    // Changes start here
    $desiredArray = $ret;

    foreach($ret as $innerArray)
    {
        $desiredArray[] = array_reverse($innerArray);
    }

    return $desiredArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help..but here also some values are missing..Please check once this if you can help regarding that.

Comment: @user3178691 What results are you getting? When I run for `n=3` and `k=2` I get `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
        )
)`

Comment: If you run that code for n=4 and k=3 then you will get followings :

(1 2 3)

(1 2 4)

(1 3 4)

(2 3 4)

(3 2 1)

(4 2 1)

(4 3 1)

(4 3 2)

Here you can see that all the numbers are not showing.

(2  4  1)

(2  3  1)

(3  4  1)

 etc are missing..